# Is it bad that my library components are not in a libraries folder in my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have three library modules in my android studio project, and the project is working fine, but I am worried that I havent  placed then in a `libraries` folder, but they are in the same folder that the `app` module is instead, like so:

[image]

So is that something bad, should I worry about it? Should I place them in a `libraries` directory? (I don't want to, though, because every time I try moving modules in/out of folders, I can barely make the project build afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to move them to `libraries` folder. The best practice is to keep all modules (both app and libraries) in the same level.

From Google developer documentation :

> There are no specific requirements on where you should store a library module, relative to a dependent application module, as long as the application module can reference the library module by a relative link. What is important is that the main module can reference the library module through a relative link.

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules)..